# Create/Access Custom Configuration Section from location tag of web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, custom-configuration

I want to add some setting for various location and also want to access that per page basis

```
<location path="Account" myAttr="true">
  <system.web>
     <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
     </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Or I want to use

```
<location path="Account">
  <myNode>true</myNode>
  <system.web>
     <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
     </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Now I want to access this setting in code. I am using MVC3 with ASP.net 4.0 .
I found an MSDN article on Custom Sections .

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx

I am not able to use that in location tags.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I have some heavy modules. 
I want to load that module on particular request only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add `~` to the path : `<location path="~/Account/LogIn">`

and I didn't use any `true`... (and it works well).

Maybe you should add suitable class and attributes.